# Rescaling for a solution of heat equation and its limit

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$u(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is solution to heat equation,

$\partial_{t}u-\Delta u=0.$

Initial condition is,

$u(0,x)=u_{0}(x)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Rescaled function $v(t,x)$ is as follows.

$v(t,x)=t^{\frac{n}{2}}u(t,x\sqrt{t})$.

I want to find $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty}v(t,x)$.

I tried change of variable $y=x\sqrt{t}$.

Then, $u(t,y)=t^{-\frac{n}{2}}v\left(t,\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$ and

\begin{multline}
\partial_{t}u-\Delta u=-\frac{n}{2}t^{-\frac{n}{2}-1}v\left(t,\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)+t^{-\frac{n}{2}}v_{t}\left(t,\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{n+3}{2}}y\cdot Dv\left(t,\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)-t^{-\frac{n}{2}-1}\Delta v\left(t,\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\\
\end{multline}

But I have no idea how to find the limit of $v$ ...

Comment: Do you know how to write an explicit formula for $u$ in terms of the fundamental solution of the heat equation? Alternatively, use the Fourier transform.

Comment: Do you mean convolution of $u_{0}$ and fundamental solution? Yes, I know but is it unique? As I know, such solution is unique when we assume solution is in $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Or when $u$ has some good decay.

Comment: $u_0 \in L^1$ is good enough to use both approaches (fundamental solution or Fourier transform). In fact in order see what is going on, just consider the case where $u$ is the fundamental solution.

Comment: Okay, I see now. I will try what you recommend. Thanks : )